# Oracle pivoting for text issue

Tags: oracle, pivot

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Codes | ColumnD | ColumnE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Type1 | Text1 | Yes |
| 1 | A | Type1 | Text2 | Yes |
| 1 | B | Type2 | Text3 | Yes |
| 2 | C | Type1 | Text4 | No |
| 2 | D | Type2 | Text5 | No |
| 2 | E | Type3 | Text6 | No |

I want to be able to pivot on Column B to have the view look something like the below:

| ColumnA | Type1 - ColumnB | Type2 - ColumnB | Type3 - ColumnB | Type2 - ColumnD | Type2 - ColumnD | Type3 - ColumnD | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | NA | Text1 & Text2 | Text3 | NA | Yes |
| 2 | C | D | E | Text4 | Text5 | Text6 | No |

Pleas note column E is associated with Column A so can only 1 value for each recording Column A

Comment: Please post the code you currently have and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Hint : **Conditional Aggregation** ( There are tons of samples might be found through seach by `[oracle][pivot]` or `[oracle][dynamic-pivot]` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` function to number the rows according to the `columnb` values for each `columna` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT columna,
       "1_TYPE_B" AS type_1_b,
       "2_TYPE_B" AS type_2_b,
       "3_TYPE_B" AS type_3_b,
       "1_TYPE_D" AS type_1_d,
       "2_TYPE_D" AS type_2_d,
       "3_TYPE_D" AS type_3_d,
       columne
FROM   (
  SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD, ColumnE,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnB) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(columnB) AS type_b,
  LISTAGG(columnD, ' & ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY columnD) AS type_d
  FOR rnk IN (
    1 AS "1", 2 AS "2", 3 AS "3"
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ColumnA, ColumnB, Codes, ColumnD, ColumnE) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'Type1', 'Text1', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 'Type1', 'Text2', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 'Type2', 'Text3', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C', 'Type1', 'Text4', 'No'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'D', 'Type2', 'Text5', 'No'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E', 'Type3', 'Text6', 'No'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMNA | TYPE_1_B | TYPE_2_B | TYPE_3_B | TYPE_1_D | TYPE_2_D | TYPE_3_D | COLUMNE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | *null* | Text1 & Text2 | Text3 | *null* | Yes |
| 2 | C | D | E | Text4 | Text5 | Text6 | No |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3a3fP1S5)